# ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AttrRes.class

Tags: android, gradle, annotations

I am facing, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AttrRes.class

build.gradle file (main project)

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.8.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'
    compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1') {
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
    compile('com.segment.analytics.android:all:2.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+') {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':contactsChipView')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Files in /libs directory (main project):

```
gson-2.2.3.jar
Parse-1.9.2.jar
YoutubeAnddroidPlayerApi.jar
```

Files in /libs directory (facebook module):

```
android-support-v4.jar
bolts.jar
```

As you can see the above gradle file, I have tried adding exclude for almost all dependencies. But still, no luck.

I also tried changing build tools from 22.0.1 to 22.0.0, even this didn't work.

I went through other posts, but no luck.

Anybody knows how to solve this?